# LARGE function throws error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to compute average scores over top k exams. That's why I need to get top k scores. There is a large function in excel, but I am not even able to execute it in a simple list in excel because it throws an error message. I also attached the screenshot of that situation. Any helps will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is the comma the correct argument separator for your Windows Regional Settings?  Some use a semicolon. eg:  `=large(a2:a9;1)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That must be the issue. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple:
Write the formula using `;` as separator instead of `,`
like this: `=LARGE(A2:A9;1)`.

Excel is weird as regarding the argument separator, deciding
on which of the two to use, depending on where in the world is
your computer situated. It has no relation to the language
your computer uses.

(Another weirdo from Microsoft that was never corrected in decades.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What a silly problem.

Comment: I would call it criminal rather than silly, because it means that communicating spreadsheets internationally is impossible without some manipulations.

Comment: I do respect your opinion.